# Carousel touch swipe implementation

Tags: jquery, touch, carousel, swipe

We have a carousel on our website that features our team.

What I realized is, that **the touch-swipe gestures of jquery mobile are not very forgiving though.**
When you want to swipe trough the carousel, but move the finger a little too much up/down, **the page will scroll AND the carousel swipes**. If you just want to look trough the carousel quickly this leads to the annoying scene that the carousel gets pushed up/down more and more, until it's not longer visible.

I was curious of how to fix it. The snippet I came up with works perfectly with the Chrome-debugger but unfortunately not on actual touch devices. There I can swipe the carousel, but not scroll the website (when I scroll on the carousel).

What am I missing here?

**Edit: Just tested on Android+Chrome and it works very smooth there.
So now I'm only stuck with IOS+Safari not working.**

Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/bgzh8ea6/

```
var slidedOnce;
var xTouch;
var yTouch;
var thresholdY = 30;

$("#myCarousel").on("touchstart", function(event) {      
    if (!slidedOnce) {
      xTouch = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      yTouch = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    }
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("#myCarousel").on("touchmove", function(event) {
  if (!slidedOnce) {
    $(this).bind("touchmove", preventDefault);
    var xDrag = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    var yDrag = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    if (Math.abs(Math.floor(yTouch - yDrag)) > thresholdY) {
      $(this).unbind("touchmove", preventDefault);
      slidedOnce = true;
    } else {
      if (Math.floor(xTouch - xDrag) > 30) {
        $(this).carousel("next");
        slidedOnce = true;
      } else if (Math.floor(xTouch - xDrag) < -30) {
        $(this).carousel("prev");
        slidedOnce = true;
      }
    }
  }
});

$("#myCarousel").on("touchend", function() {
  slidedOnce = false;
  $(this).bind("touchmove", preventDefault);
});

function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: You can use this very useful plugin : http://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: Thanks, I still would like to know what's going wrong up there though :P